# Removing an automatic constraint in IB

Tags: uiscrollview, nslayoutconstraint

I'm creating the content for a UIScrollView in interface builder, the uiview is inside the uiscrollview and it has the following properties:

- top to superview
- bottom to superview
- left to superview
- width: 1536

But for some reason I cannot remove an automatic constraint 'right: -768', I can see why it thinks it should add this, however, I've set that view's left to be constrained to the superviews left and set it a absolute width. Surely I should be able to delete it?

It's giving me an annoying bug, so when I try to scroll the view, that -768 is added, making the second page of the scroll view not visible, and instead making a ghost 'third page' visible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, I answered this on another website and forgot about SO.

I removed it by setting it an IBOutlet and removing it programatically.

Answer (score 0):

IB does not let you specify ambiguous or unsatisfiable constraints. You can not remove the constraint because lacking it your constraints will be ambiguous.